# Utilizing Excel's Functions with vb.net (borders etc..)

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am currently working on an application that adds to existing excel spreadsheets at data is entered.. Simple right?  I am having an issue finding information on the worksheet formatting ( Borders, Creating Hyperlinks, Background Colors etc.. ) I have searched all over the place and most of what I find will not work for me.  I am running Visual Studio Pro 2013.  The intelli sense does not seem to work with most of the Excel stuff on my computer for some reason, is there a Site or something that lists functions and how to access them?  I have referenced the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library in the COM portion of the Reference Manager as well as Microsoft Office Tools Excel in the Assemblies.

Here is my Code:

```
 Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
 Imports System.Reflection
 Imports System.IO

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    If jobnumtext.Text.Length > 2 And provincetext.Text.Length > 0 And contractnumbertext.Text.Length > 2 And clienttext.Text.Length > 0 Then

        thisdate = DateTime.Now
        thismonth = Month(thisdate)
        name = MonthName(thismonth, True)

        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\IP Address\qa_qc\003. Quality Management\005. Project Management\Project Logs\Job Set Up\Job Set Up Log_Current.xlsx")
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(name.ToString())

        Dim sheet As Worksheet = oExcel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(0)

        Try
        With oSheet
                If oExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                    lrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*",
                                       After:=.Range("A1"),
                                       LookAt:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                       LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                                       SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                       SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                                       MatchCase:=False).Row
                Else
                    lrow = 1
                End If
            End With

            oSheet.Range("A" & lrow + 1).Value = dateissued.Text
            oSheet.Range("B" & lrow + 1).Value = contractnumbertext.Text
            oSheet.Range("C" & lrow + 1).Value = clienttext.Text
            oSheet.Range("D" & lrow + 1).Value = provincetext.Text
            oSheet.Range("E" & lrow + 1).Value = locationtext.Text
            oSheet.Range("F" & lrow + 1).Value = attentiontext.Text
            oSheet.Range("G" & lrow + 1).Value = foremantext.Text
            oSheet.Range("H" & lrow + 1).Value = peopletext.Text
            oSheet.Range("I" & lrow + 1).Value = setupbytext.Text
            oSheet.Range("J" & lrow + 1).Value = startdate.Text
            oSheet.Range("K" & lrow + 1).Value = enddate.Text
            oSheet.Range("L" & lrow + 1).Value = Pipeline.ToString()
            oSheet.Range("M" & lrow + 1).Value = facility.ToString()
            oSheet.Range("N" & lrow + 1).Value = hourly.ToString()
            oSheet.Range("O" & lrow + 1).Value = holdback.ToString() & " " & holdbackstext.Text & b.ToString()
            oSheet.Range("P" & lrow + 1).Value = Discounts.ToString() & " " & discountstext.Text & dis.ToString()
            oSheet.Range("Q" & lrow + 1).Value = LOA.ToString() & " " & lo.ToString() & loatext.Text
            oSheet.Range("R" & lrow + 1).Value = RateSchedule.ToString() & " " & rateschedtext.Text
            oSheet.Range("S" & lrow + 1).Value = WPS.ToString() & " " & wpstext.Text
            oSheet.Range("T" & lrow + 1).Value = projectdesctext.Text
            oSheet.Range("U" & lrow + 1).Value = filesname.ToString()

            oSheet.Columns("A:T").WrapText = True
            oSheet.Columns("A:T").AutoFit()
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 10
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 17
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 17
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 16
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 12
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 12
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 10
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 12
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 10
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 10
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 8
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 8
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 15
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 15
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("P:P").ColumnWidth = 15
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 15
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("R:R").ColumnWidth = 15
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("S:S").ColumnWidth = 20
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("T:T").ColumnWidth = 80
            oExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("U:U").ColumnWidth = 20

            oBook.Save()
            oBook.Close()
            oSheet = Nothing
            oBook = Nothing
            oExcel.Quit()
            oExcel = Nothing
            GC.Collect()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            oExcel.Quit()
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    Else : MessageBox.Show("Sorry you must input all information to Continue!", "Missing Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
```

I want to create a hyperlink to Column "U" an have absolutely no idea how..
Also I would like to add borders to every new entry on the document.

I'm not sure how everything works with the references to the libraries in excel any information help or direction would so very much appreciated!

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Teach a man to fish...*

Since you have the basics of creating references to your sheets and stuff, this will be easy.  What I do is record a macro in MS Excel and see what the VBA is. Then do the same thing in my VB code.  Using this concept, you can do anything you want without having to search relentlessly on the web for keywords you don't even know.

Comment: I keep getting Parameter violations... here's what I have came up with: oExcel.Range("U" & lrow.ToString()).Select()
         oExcel.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Address:="\\File Location\qa_qc\003. Quality Management\005. Project Management\Project Logs\Job Set Up")

Comment: Your intellisense should be showing you that you need at least 2 parameters on the `add()` method. First one is your range and the second is your address. You will notice that your `Range.Select()` method returns a `Range` object. Put this into a variable and pass that as the `Anchor` parameter. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick. I just tested this on my PC also running VS2013.
This will add a hyperlink in Column E to column U in the same row.

```
Private Sub Sheet1_Change( Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) Handles Me.Change

    Dim activeSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(Me.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

    Dim jobnum As Int32 = CType(Range("A" + Target.Row.ToString()).Value, Int32)

    If (jobnum > 1)
        Application.EnableEvents = False 
        activeSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(activeSheet.Range("E" + Target.Row.ToString()), "", "U" + Target.Row.ToString())
        Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay on quick question sorry, + Target.Row.Tostring() If I  Dim Target As String = "File Location" I get Row is not a member of "String"

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to post this as an answer it was too large to fit in a comment section.
Now I am getting a:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): The server threw an exception..... at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlinks.Add(Object Anchor, String Address, Object SubAddress, Object SreenTip, Object TextToDisplay)`

I just want to Clarify one thing... I am using:

```
Dim activesheet as Excel.Worksheet = CType(oExcel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(name.ToString()), Excel.Worksheet) 
With oExcel.Worksheets(name.ToString())
Dim rng as String = oExcel.Range("U10").Select()
activesheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=rng, Address:="File Location")
End With
```

The `Range.Select()` Method returns True or False which does not seem correct to me...

I tried the Excel Macro recorder this is what it gave me:

```
Range("U1").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, 
Address:="File Location", 
TextToDisplay:=_
```

Can I get some direction to incorporate this now, for Intellisense to Display `Activesheet` I must use `oExcel.ActiveSheet` is this the Same?  I assigned `oExcel as Excel.Application` earlier in my code.  I apologize for not being to understand this it is really confusing me for some reason...